# How to test a sleep function in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, sleep

I have written my own sleep function and want to test it. Following is my code:

```
func TestSleep(t *testing.T) {
    start := time.Now()
    mySleepFunction(65)
    end := time.Now()
    if (end - start) != 65 {
        t.Error("Incorrect sleep function")
    }
}
```

This is not working. I am trying to get start time and end time and then compare it with expected time. The expected time will be in seconds. I tried `end.Sub(start)` but this returns me something like `1m30.0909`, instead I need `90` as a result. It would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks :)

Comment: you need have some time to read the api reference.there is a type `Duration`.

Comment: You can mess with durations, or you could simply subtract int values. time.Now() - time.Now() does not return a time.Second duration.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if your sleep function passes the test ?

Comment: Why create your own sleep function when time.Sleep() is available?

Answer (score 15):

**Elapsed time:**

The easiest to get the elapsed time since a specific time (`start`) is to use the [`time.Since()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) function which returns a [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) which has a [`Duration.Seconds()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Seconds) method which returns the duration in seconds as `float64`.

So in your case the elapsed seconds:

```
sec := time.Since(start).Seconds()
```

**Now on to testing...**

When testing sleep-like functions you should take into consideration that after the sleep it is not guaranteed that the code will continue to execute immediately. For example quoting from the doc of [`time.Sleep()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep):

> Sleep pauses the current goroutine for **at least** the duration d.

So when writing test code for sleep-like functions, I would test like this:

- elapsed time should be at least the specified,
- and allow some error margin.

So for example test it like this:

```
func TestSleep(t *testing.T) {
    const secSleep = 65.0

    start := time.Now()
    mySleepFunction(int(secSleep))
    sec := time.Since(start).Seconds()

    if sec < secSleep || sec > secSleep*1.05 {
        t.Error("Incorrect sleep function")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I didn't know of the Since function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use time.Unix() which gives you the amount of seconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970 UTC.) then your test should work.

```
func TestSleep(t *testing.T) {
    start := time.Now().Unix()
    mySleepFunction(65)
    end := time.Now().Unix()
    if (end - start) != 65{
        t.Error("Incorrect sleep function")
    }
}
```

Currently, your code is subtracting a time.Now() which doesn't return the result you intend. Your test wants simple int values that represent seconds.